# How to set a listener on array of checkboxes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Situation:

Trying to 'collect' all checkboxes with this:

```
let docChildPermissions = $('input.docPermission').not('.parent');
```

And that works.

Now I just want to make an action if any of these checkboxes is changed like this;

```
$(document).on('change', $(docChildPermissions), function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

But in console I get this:

```
init [document, context: document]
0: document
context: document
length: 1
__proto__: Object(0)
```

This is the whole document that gets 'console logged' and I need only that selected checkbox.

Comment: jQuery has the [.not() Method](https://api.jquery.com/not/) but also (specifically the [Sizzle engine](https://sizzlejs.com/)) a [:not Selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [documentation for `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you'll see that the selector argument has to be a string, not a jQuery object as in your example. This is the cause of the problem.

To fix this, convert the object to a string selector, like this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.docPermission:not(.parent)', function() {
  console.log($(this));
});
```